# Read lines from a file using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have to create a script who read the NUMBER of lines from any file.
I've thought to use the structure do / while. How i can do it?

Comment: Did you look similar questions on the topic and make an attempt?

Comment: yes but i have not found anything.

Comment: also this.. the funny thing is I just took your title and copy-pasted it into google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash

Comment: this show me the lines... I only want the NUMBER of lines

Comment: `wc -l <filename>`

Comment: @DavidCep extrapolate a little - if you know how to read each line, you can surely count how many lines you've read.

Answer (score 0):

## Syntax to read file line by line on a Bash Unix & Linux shell:

The syntax is as follows for bash, ksh, zsh, and all other shells –

1) while read -r line; do COMMAND; done < input.file

2) The -r option passed to read command prevents backslash escapes from being interpreted.

3) Add IFS= option before read command to prevent leading/trailing whitespace from being trimmed -
while IFS= read -r line; do COMMAND_on $line; done < input.file

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=0
input="/path/to/txt/file"
while IFS= read -r var
do
  echo "$var"
  COUNTER=$[$COUNTER +1]
done < "$input"
echo " $COUNTER "
```

Comment: i only want to show the number of lines

Comment: you can add counter.

Comment: can you show me how please?

Comment: yes why not wait ok.

Comment: i updated my answer please check it hope it helps